# How to center title in ggplot() and theme_void()

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, title

I'm a medical scientist wokring on a stroke reserach project for many years. Unfortunately our statician moved so I have now to deal with all problems. I have a minor problem, which I unfortunately coulnd't solve despite long reasearch on google and SO. I would like to creat some plots with the graphs on the left side and the p-Value on the right side. I managed so far to create the plot, but I'm not able to move the title "p-value" aligned in the middle of the right plot. i tried the function theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)), but then coordinates appear within my p-values (see examples). do you know, what i can do? thank you soooo much!!

The code and plot so far:

```
mod_coco_bsl <- lmer(coco ~ exposure + age.bsl.centered + pat.sex + education + 
                    bmi.centered + sport + active_smoker + prev.stroke + prev.diabetes + prev.hypertonie + gds.cat + 
                    (1|center) + crphs + il6, data=dt_bsl)
#summary(mod_coco_bsl)
ci_coco <- confint(mod_coco_bsl, oldNames=FALSE)

output <- tidy(mod_coco_bsl, conf.int=TRUE, exponentiate=FALSE, effects="fixed")[,-1]
kable(output[,c(1,2,7,8,6)], digits=c(2,2,2,2,3))

cocopvalue <- c(0,0,0,0)
i <- 1
while (i <= length(cocopvalue)) {
  cocopvalue[i] <- (output[i+1,6])
  i<-i+1
}
cocopvalue <- unlist(cocopvalue, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
cocopvalue <- round(cocopvalue, digits = 4)



# plot
res_coco <- data.frame("term"=c("1", "2-3", "4-5", ">5"), 
                  "estimate" = summary(mod_coco_bsl)$coefficients[2:5,1], 
                  "conf.low" = ci_coco[4:7,1], 
                  "conf.high"= ci_coco[4:7,2])
res_coco$term <- factor(res_coco$term, levels=c("1", "2-3", "4-5", ">5") )

(plot_coco <- ggplot(res_coco, aes(y = estimate, x = term, col=term)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), size = 0.8)+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dotted", size = 1) +
    labs(title= "CoCo-Scores in different coffee consumer groups",y = "Effect estimate on CoCo score", x = "Consumed cups of coffee per day") +
    coord_flip(ylim = c(-0.1, 0.35)) +
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.position="none", axis.text=element_text(size=14, face = "bold"), axis.title=element_text(size=18), plot.title =   element_text(size=22)) + theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 3)) #+ annotate(geom="text", x=1.1, y=1.6, label="B", size=8)
  )


p_right <- 
  ggplot() +  
  geom_text(
    aes(x = 0, y = c("1","2-3","4-5",5), label = cocopvalue ),
    hjust = 0,
    fontface =  "plain") + 
    labs(title="p-value", fontface ="bold") +
  theme_void()


layout <- c(
  area(t = 0, l = 0, b = 30, r = 9),
  area(t = 1, l = 9, b = 30, r = 11)
)

plot_coco + p_right +plot_layout(design = layout)
```

The resulting graph:
[image: The resulting graph:]

[image: and the graph with the suggested theme(plot.title...)]

In found a nice tutorial here:

https://www.khstats.com/blog/forest-plots/#just-the-code

and i tried the theme(plot.title) argument, but without success, since a coordinate system appears thereafter

Comment: Put `theme_void()` before `theme(plot.title)`

Comment: @M Aurélio. Thank you so much Aurélio. It totally worked!!! Have a nice weekend